# Why do question mark characters appear when changing the permissions of directory?

Tags: command-line, permissions

I am trying to change permissions of a folder temporarily  whose initial permissions are

```
user@ubuntu:/var/log$ ls -l squid*
squid3:
total 4
-rw-r----- 1 proxy proxy    0 Jan 16 14:43 access.log
-rw-r----- 1 proxy proxy 1359 Jan 16 14:43 cache.log
ls: cannot open directory squid-deb-proxy: Permission denied
```

to some thing following

```
user@ubuntu:/var/log$ sudo chmod -R 644 squid*
user@ubuntu:/var/log$ ls -l squid*
squid3:
ls: cannot access squid3/cache.log: Permission denied
ls: cannot access squid3/access.log: Permission denied
total 0
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? access.log
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? cache.log

squid-deb-proxy:
ls: cannot access squid-deb-proxy/store.log: Permission denied
ls: cannot access squid-deb-proxy/cache.log: Permission denied
ls: cannot access squid-deb-proxy/access.log: Permission denied
total 0
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? access.log
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? cache.log
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? store.log
```

You will notice after the change of permissions there are question marks everywhere. Why is this happening? I basically want to read the access log to see if squid-deb-proxy server is getting requests from client or not.

Comment: Note that in Ubuntu 21.10 there is a known bug that causes this issue on ZFS: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/zfs-linux/+bug/1906476

Answer (score 65, accepted):

To view the permissions of a directory, you need to pass the `-d` flag to `ls`, like this:

```
ls -ld squid3
```

To read a file, its read permission needs to be set. However, **to read a directory and the listing of its files, both the read and the execute permissions need to be set**. If they aren't, you get weird errors like the ones you're experiencing.

To set the read permission on files and the read and execute permissions on directories recursively, use this command:

```
chmod -R a+rX directoryname
```

Here's an explanation of that command:

- `chmod` is the name of the command, use for changing the permissions of files.
- `-R` is the recursive flag. It means apply this command to the directory, and all of its children, and of its children's children, and so on.
- `a` stands for all: apply these permissions the owner of the file, the group owner of the file, and all other users.
- `+` means add the following permissions if they aren't set already.
- `r` means the read permission.
- `X` means the execute permission, but only on directories. Lower-case `x` would mean the execute permission on both files and directories.

More information is found in the [manpage for the `chmod` command [image: Manpage icon]](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/chmod.1).

Comment: is there any thing wrong with using `chmod -R 644 squid*`

Comment: @RegisteredUser: yes. 644 is `rw-r--r--`, which is suitable for files, but not for directories. Directories need to have the execute permission set too, like this: `rwxr-xr-x` or 755. The command you mentioned unsets the execute permission on all files and directories recursively, which causes these errors.

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem too.  I couldn't do chmod or chown on the file.
I had tried to delete it.  It turns out that trying to delete it (rm command) caused the problem.  The kicker is that **the file is shared between two different systems**.  **Once I closed the file in the other system, the file disappeared.**
Here's more details of my configuration.
system 1: Ubuntu guest VM.  This is where I did the rm command.
system 2: Windows 7 host.  This is where I had opened the file using the less command (in cygwin, not that it's necessarily relevant).

Answer (score 2):

As you stated that your goal is to read `/var/log/squid/access.log`, your best solution is to type `sudo less /var/log/squid/access.log`, which spares the trouble of repeatedly chmodding.