# File with strange permissions

Tags: permissions

I am trying to access an image file in my code, but my code is telling that it does not exist. However, listing the directory where the image is I can see it, but I got the following strange output when showing its permissions:

```
??????????   ? ?       ?         ?            ? class3705.png
```

I also cannot see it using Nautilus in the folder.

When I try to change its permissions I have the following error:

```
chmod 644 class3705.png
chmod: cannot access `class3705.png': Invalid argument
```

I even cannot copy it to another place to change its permissions, it returns me the following error:

```
cp: cannot stat `class3705.png': Invalid argument
```

It never happened to me before and I really don't want to erase this file because I don't know if it is the only one with this error. Is there any other way to recover this file?

EDIT: here you can see the ls [image: ls] and chmod [image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do question mark characters appear when changing the permissions of directory?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/243999/why-do-question-mark-characters-appear-when-changing-the-permissions-of-director)

Comment: Not a duplicate because he is not trying to change a directory . and @OP can you give output of ls command ?

Comment: @Raja ls shows class3705.png but ls -la shows  ??????????   ? ?       ?         ?            ? class3705.png

Comment: do this in your terminal , `cd ..;chmod -R 755 ./* `and try again.

Comment: when I tried to change the permission of the whole directory where the image is I got the error chmod: cannot access `H225BIS11.tif/class3705.png': Invalid argument

Comment: @Raja my error is chmod: cannot access `./class3705.png': Invalid argument

Comment: Can you post entire log of ls and chmod in pastebin and share link. Thank you

Comment: The permission of the directory where the image is is the following: drwxr-xr-x 2 anselmo recod 12288 Dec 10 23:08 H225BIS11.tif

Comment: @Raja see my editition on the post. Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33565/discussion-between-raja-and-anselmo-ferreira).